Can't start Android Virtual Device stopped at 'found magic skin'
Previously, the emulator ran perfectly until I had to reinstall Arch Linux on my laptop. I installed it on a BTRFS filesystem, and the home partition as well (previously EXT4). Then I installed Android Studio and created a virtual device but it couldn't be run.
AVD Error
I tried running it through the terminal and it displayed a log like below.
./emulator -verbose -avd Pixel_8_Pro_API_35 -log-nofilter

INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-USER/emu-crash-34.1.18.db, detection is enabled for process: 994716
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.1.18.0 (build_id 11481568) (CL:N/A)
DEBUG   | Current emulator version 34.1.18 is the same as the required version 34.1.18.
INFO    | Found AVD name 'Pixel_8_Pro_API_35'
INFO    | Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
INFO    | argv[0]: './emulator'; program directory: '/home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator'
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/USER/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-35/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
INFO    | emuDirName: '/home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator'
INFO    | try dir /home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator
INFO    | Trying emulator path '/home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64'
INFO    | Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64'
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++'
DEBUG   | emulator: Running :/home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[00] = "/home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[01] = "-verbose"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[02] = "-avd"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[03] = "Pixel_8_Pro_API_35"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[04] = "-log-nofilter"
DEBUG   | Concatenated backend parameters:  /home/USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -verbose -avd Pixel_8_Pro_API_35 -log-nofilter
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-USER/emu-crash-34.1.18.db, detection is enabled for process: 994716
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -skin 1344x2992
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -skindir (null)
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -kernel /home/USER/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-35/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//kernel-ranchu
DEBUG   | Target arch = 'x86_64'
DEBUG   | Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
DEBUG   | Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -ramdisk /home/USER/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-35/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//ramdisk.img
DEBUG   | Using initial system image: /home/USER/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-35/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//system.img
DEBUG   | Using initial vendor image: /home/USER/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-35/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//vendor.img
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -initdata (null)
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -cache /home/USER/.android/avd/../avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_35.avd/cache.img
DEBUG   | autoconfig: -sdcard /home/USER/.android/avd/../avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_35.avd/sdcard.img
DEBUG   | foldable or large screen devices with api >=33 is set to have minimum ram 3G
INFO    | Increasing RAM size to 3072MB
DEBUG   | VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 576MB,setting it to that value
DEBUG   | System image is read only
DEBUG   | Failed to parse IPv6 DNS address fe80::1%enp6s0f1
DEBUG   | Found 2 DNS servers:
DEBUG   |       192.168.0.1
DEBUG   |       fe80::1
DEBUG   | Starting hostapd main loop.
DEBUG   | found magic skin width=1344 height=2992 bpp=16
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

KVM can run smoothly. I ran sudo kvm-ok and it gave output like below. Genymotion emulator also works fine.
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used

To be more specific, the emulated performance option cannot be changed.
Emulated performance option
I tried running it using iGPU as well but it couldn't, the log output is the same as above. (I'm using a laptop with Optimus configuration managed by envycontrol, running on Nvidia GPU and connected to an external monitor).
./emulator -verbose -gpu guest -avd Pixel_8_Pro_API_35 -log-nofilter

Is this a problem with the GPU or emulation settings? or the emulator cannot run on a BTRFS partition?
Thankyou :)
